access denied by server while mounting a share
Server permissions (Includes data/ subject of mount):
root@nas:/mnt/user# ls -lh
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nobody users 152 Sep 25 18:08 appdata -> ../cache/appdata/
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody users  84 Sep 28 18:00 appdata_backup/
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody users  16 Sep 27 19:30 data/
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody users   0 Aug 11 22:26 domains/
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody users   6 Sep 30 13:43 han-domain/
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody users   6 Aug 11 22:26 isos/
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody users  22 Sep 27 20:01 my-domain/
drwxrwxrwx 1 nobody users  26 Aug 11 22:26 system/
root@nas:/mnt/user#

Ubuntu 24.04 mount point named nas-media:
makem@makem-22:/media$ ls -lh
total 12K
drwxrwxrwx 1 root  root  4.0K Sep 27 00:58 games
drwxr-xr-x 7 root  root  4.0K Sep 30 13:17 makem
drwxr-xr-x 2 makem makem 4.0K Sep 27 12:53 nas-media

Linux mount command:
makem@makem-22:/media$ sudo mount  -t nfs 192.168.1.249:/data /media/nas-media
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.249:/data
makem@makem-22:/media$

I fail to see why it is denied.

What does /etc/exports look like on your NAS?

Correct command (path)
sudo mount  -t nfs 192.168.1.249:/mnt/user/data /media/nas-media
